# SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (ntoskrnl) on virtualization software other than Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, intel-core-i5

System specs: https://pastebin.com/AGNZgAUT

Hello.

I tried using some virtualization software (VMware, Nox App Player, and Hyper-V) with Intel VT-x enabled, however with everything except Hyper-V, I get a bluescreen for ntoskrnl.exe, under the bug check string "SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION" with a stop code of 0x0000003b.

Minidump of one of the crashes: https://files.catbox.moe/ptk8he.dmp

Analysis from WinDBG: https://pastebin.com/Yb7Zw5Re

Comment: If you are going to run VMWare products you must disable Hyper-V.

Comment: @Ramhound I had done that, it still crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had actually figured this out.

I am using a Insider Preview version of Windows, so I installed another drive and installed the October update. Once that was done, I installed VMware and started a machine up, so it worked.

I think it's something involving the Insider kernel, but I don't know.